# Correct URL path for multi-site domain tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, event-tracking

I have a site

```
https://www.example.com
```

Also hosted on this site is a language version of that site, which has its own view in Google Analytics:

```
https://www.example.com/de-de/
```

My question is, when setting up a goal on the second site, what is the correct goal path to use? Do I need to include the full URL, the /de-de/ or simply the filepath after this?

[image: Google Analytics screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

No, don't insert the domain there, it's just the path after the TLD that is needed.

For example:-

```
/category/sub/page
/category/sub/page.html
```

Comment: So in this case, you're saying I would need to include the /de-de/ in the path?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to include `/de-de/` in the path unless you have your Google Analytics profile set up for `/de-de/` exclusively.